# Is it possible to arrange Java Script files in to 'name spaces' to avoid conflicts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, javascript-namespaces

I'm building a website using a premium html template, part of the template is in Javascript. So in the template I have something like this - its in the 'master template' every page.

```
//Template JS
<script src="/js/core.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

Also as part of this website I am using an ecommerce plugin and those files also need to be on the page, so something like this:

```
//Plgin JS

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/underscore.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/App_Plugins/Merchello/client/js/merchello.ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/App_Plugins/Merchello/client/js/merchello.ui.settings.js"></script>
        <script src="~/App_Plugins/Merchello/client/js/fasttrack.js"></script>
```

The problem is the JS conflicts when they are all on the page together. is there a way to group the java script files in a way they they can only see whats in that group... like a namespace kind of concept?

Or will I just have to unpick it all?

Comment: You may want to read up on javascript module loaders like https://requirejs.org/ or http://capmousse.github.io/include.js/.

Comment: No, they're all gonna run in the same "space."

Answer (score -1):

Using `script` tags in the same `html` page no because browser creates only one global space which visible and shared between all scripts.

You can try to use some module bundlers like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), [requirejs](https://requirejs.org/) etc.
Or you can use [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) to create a page inside page and move the plugin html and scripts to the `iframe`.